# Why is my Swift for-in-loop not executing/iterating?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to delete an array of NSManagedObjects associated with a CoreData model. I'm creating a new instance of the class my property is apart of, and attempting to delete each item within. Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // THIS FOR IN LOOP WILL NOT EXECUTE...
        for x in DrilledDownCategoryViewController().categoryItemsItems {
            println("^^^")
            managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(x as NSManagedObject)
        }

        // EVERYTHING ELSE WILL THOUGH...
        println("asdfjkl;")

        let logItemToDelete = categoryItems[indexPath.row]

        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(logItemToDelete)

        self.fetchCategory()

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        save()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrilledDownCategoryViewController` is a class. 
`DrilledDownCategoryViewController()` is its contructor. 
With `DrilledDownCategoryViewController()` you create a new instance of your view controller rather than accessing the "running" one. 
Naturally a new Object's related array (or what ever) would be either nil or what it was set to in its constructor.

If you are used to Objective-C, this is what you did:

```
[[[DrilledDownCategoryViewController alloc] init| categoryItemsItems]
```

An Obj-C forin loop woult not iterate a single time too.

Comment: I'm used to writing JavaScript lol. Could you point me in the write direction to properly accessing the 'running' class' property value?

Comment: Not really. Apparently your code sniplet is from some table view controller. Is this the very DrilledDownCategoryViewController or how are they related? If it is the one, then use `self.categoryItemsItems` to access it or just `categoryItemsItems`.

Comment: For anyone wondering why I ran into this issue, just look at my answer below. Thanks Hermann for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The for-in-loop will not execute an empty array.

Just do this so you don't run into an empty fetch results array from another class: If you're trying to access a fetched results array of CoreData items; don't depend on accessing an array from another class. Just fetch particular predicate filtered items and inject them into a new array. You'll be able to alter or delete them from there...